# PHP & Laravel | Use OrderBy after a GroupBy

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Php code

```
 $elements= DB::table('transactions')
  ->select('product_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->groupBy('product_id')
  ->get();
```

I want to apply an orderby and a limit('5') on `count`

Any orientation ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  orderBy()  ..and take()

```
 $elements= DB::table('transactions')
  ->select('product_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->groupBy('product_id')
  ->orderBy('your_column')
  ->take(5)
  ->get();
```